Does smallness of Gromov-Hausdorff distance on scale 2 imply smallness on GH distance on scale 1?
Let $(M,g)$ be a Riemannian manifold and $C(Y)$ be a metric cone over $Y$. Let $B_r$ denote the geodesic ball of radius $r$ centered at a fixed point $x$ in $M$ and $C_r$ denote the metric ball of radius $r$ in the cone $C$ centered at the vertex. Suppose we have $d_{GH}(B_2,C_2)<\epsilon$ for some $\epsilon$, is it true that $d_{GH}(B_1,C_1)<\epsilon$?
I tried checking it using definition of Gromov-Hausdorff distance: there exists $f:B_2\to C_2$ and $g:C_2\to B_2$ $\epsilon$-Gromov-Hausdorff approximations. It is clear that $B_1$ and $f(B_1)$ are $\epsilon$ close in $d_{GH}$ but it seems hard to know that $f(B_1)$ is close to $C_1$. Couldn't $B_1$ be mapped away from the vertex and still make $d_{GH}(B_2,C_2)<\epsilon$?
The background of this question comes from T.Colding's paper Theorem 4.6 of New Monotonicity formulas For Ricci Curvature And
Application where in the proof of the theorem it writes $$\frac{1}{r}d_{GH}(B_r(x),B_{er}(v_{er}))+\frac{1}{er}d_{GH}(B_{er}(x),B_{er}(v_{er}))\le e\Theta_{er}+\Theta_{er}$$ I think the first term is somehow using the fact that I am asking here and the second term follows from definition directly. I would appreciate any ideas on the question or how to understand that line of proof of Theorem 4.6.
